# merge two files as prefix of another

Tags: bash

I have two files as a.txt and b.txt

`$cat a.txt`

`a`

and

`$cat b.txt`

b

I want the output like this.

`$cat result.txt`

`ab`

Comment: Did you try `cat a.txt b.txt > result.txt`? If yes and it did not work as you expected what went wrong?

Comment: this should be the output if i try what you have described.
`$cat result.txt`

`a`

`b`

Comment: It goes row way.
But i want in column way.

Comment: paste one worked for me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf '%s%s\n' "$(<a.txt)" "$(<b.txt)"
```